# Redefine Python object method?

Tags: python, object, monkeypatching, redefinition

Suppose I have a class `Foobar` and I want to redefine a method of one of its instances:

```py
class Foobar:
    def myMethod(self):
        print('this method was not overridden')

foo = Foobar()

def foo.myMethod:
    print('this method was overridden')
```

Problem is, this approach throws errors. Is there a way to redefine object methods?

Comment: Frame challenge: why would you want to do that? The purpose of a class is to define behavior for *all* its instances. If `foo` is supposed to behave differently, then `foo` probably shouldn't be an instance of `Foobar`. (Having `myMethod` check an attribute of an instance in order to behave one way or another is another matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new method and assign it

```py
def new_method():
    print("Hello")

foo.myMethod = new_method
```

Comment: This creates a new `function`-valued instance attribute, not a method.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called monkeypatching.

Methods are non-data descriptors, which means that anything you put in the instance `__dict__` with the same name will override it:

```
class Foobar:
    def myMethod(self):
        print('this method was not overridden')

foo = Foobar()
```

`type(foo.myMethod)` shows `method`.

```
def myMethod():
    print('this method was overridden')

foo.myMethod = myMethod
```

Now `type(foo.myMethod)` shows `function`.

Since you access `foo.myMethod()` from `foo.__dict__`, you won't be able to invoke the descriptor protocol. In other words, you won't be able to pass `self` to `myMethod`.

To fully replace the method, invoke the descriptor protocol manually, and create a bound method object:

```
def myMethod(self):
    print('this method was overridden')

foo.myMethod = myMethod.__get__(foo)
```

Now `type(foo.myMethod)` shows `method` again. This is important because if you wanted to monkey-patch the class, you could do it with the full version and have it work out of the box:

```
Foo.myMethod = myMethod
```

The first version would raise an error if you tried calling `foo.myMethod`, while the second would work as expected.